# how to create a word file on clients from aspx site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-word

my code generates a word document from some data and opens it directly.

when i start it local it works. but when i put the code in the server and try to generate it there it doesnt work.

the file should generate in the clients not on the server. is this possible?

this is how i create the word file:

```
    Dim oApp As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document

    oApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    oDoc = oApp.Documents.Add
```

afte i create the file i can open it with this command:

```
 oApp.Visible = True
```

Comment: Although i am not sure but the code seems to be running on server hence any execution will also be on server only, if you need anything to be done on client side use ActiveX objects in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running under IIS on the server.  When you run the code locally, it appears to work because your machine *is* the server and so, when Word opens, you see the window appear.  Your code is still running on the "server," though!

You can't open a document directly on a client like this, and nor will the MSWord interop classes you've used affect a client machine.  What you could do instead is create the document on the server, and then offer it as a download to your client.  Their browser would then offer to the user the typical example of "Open/Save/Cancel" and handle the file as per any other download.

If you can guarantee the presence of a plugin on the client's browser, such that the document can be made to appear in-browser, this would also be an option - the mechanism for serving the file up would be broadly the same, though.

Comment: thank you, that sound logical. how can i modify my code so that the clients recieves a download window?